# Where should custom object managers that are to be shared between apps go?

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

My Django app has several apps, each with their own `models.py`. I also have an `api` app which provides a REST API.

For model `A`, I often wanted to get data paginated a certain way (the [data-tables](https://www.datatables.net/) way). I wanted to do this in a few places (inside the `api` app and some main UI apps), so I created a custom object manager `PaginationManager` and attached it to model `A`. Then

Life was good and DRY, but now another model `B` needs to be gotten in a paginated way. I would like to use the same `PaginationManager`, but which app should it go in? Does it belong outside of any app? It seems like a lot of business logic to be putting in a `util` folder or something.

Comment: It should just go into a module like other python code that's used in many applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best practice would be to make it as general as possible and extract it into a `lib` or `utils` app that can be reused by all of your apps.

I typically will have a `utils` app that contains thinks like `paginators.py`, `serializers.py`, `mixins.py` and so on. Usually the more generic and reusable the better.

Comment: I do the same. As long as you can import it, wherever it makes sense to you, and your team, is as good a place as any.